# Постройка, сооружение, здание - как называется эта архитектурная идея?

Tags: лексика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как назвать эту конструкцию с двумя разделенными помещениями туалетных комнат? Постройка, сооружение, здание?

Answer (score 1):

По внешним признакам тип сооружения здесь можно конкретизировать как **павильон** (небольшая крытая изолированная постройка со входом для посетителей). По внутренней планировке это *сдвоенная кабина* с техническим отсеком под платёжный терминал.